# Ng-model not update inside select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select element in my HTML:

```
<select ng-if="useFlickr" class="span6" ng-model="flickrAlbum" ng-options="item.PhotosetId as item.Title for item in flickrAlbums"></select>
```

and the javascript code:

```
function ImageGalleryController($scope, $HttpTransform, ImageGallery, $notification, News, $timeout, $cacheFactory, Flickr) {
  $scope.getFlickrAlbums = getFlickrAlbums;
  function getFlickrAlbums() {
      $scope.flickrAlbums = [{ Title: "Album 1", PhotosetId: "120345" }, { Title: "Album2", PhotosetId: "13244" }];
   }     
}
```

but my model flickrAlbum, does not updating when i change the value.

Comment: What's `ng` in the JS?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code. Always use object in `ng-model` as any child scopes will break 2 way binding

Comment: Is this getFlickrAlbums method in a controller? Where is ng declared? Shouldn't ng be $scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that ngIf directive creates a new child scope. As the result `ng-model="flickrAlbum"` you defined points to the inner scope (and updates it too). However, it won't affect original outer scope model.

So you either use $parent reference to get hold of original model:

```
<select ng-if="useFlickr" class="span6" 
        ng-model="$parent.flickrAlbum" 
        ng-options="item.PhotosetId as item.Title for item in flickrAlbums"></select> {{ flickrAlbum }}
```

.. or preinitialize model in controller (however, note that you might need to pass entire object as ngModel value instead of current approach with just `PhotosetId` as a model).

Comment: you are welcome, this is tricky problems. ngIf/ngInclude/ngSwitch creates new scopes, so need to remember about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model variable needs to be separate and distinct from the the option collection. You will then reference that model in your controller to do work on the current album. The collection itself is not modified by the process of making a selection.

```
<select ng-if="useFlickr" class="span6" ng-model="selectedAlbum" ng-options="item.PhotosetId as item.Title for item in flickrAlbums"></select>
```

[Angular Docs for ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)